# Send all WIFI through TUN/UDP (except 1 UDP port)

Tags: vpn, routing, iptables, tunnel

I have set up a UDP tunnel using TUN. So I have an app on both sides that does the following.

```
   local     <-->      remote
   -----               ------
tun <--> udp <--> udp <--> tun
```

I want all the WIFI traffic on my machines to go through the TUN but of course I need my app to still be able to read/write the WIFI interface in order to bridge between the TUN and WIFI(UDP).

Perhaps I can set up that traffic to all ports except 1 go to the TUN and that 1 remaining port goes to WIFI? Is there a better way?

Comment: OpenVPN does it by setting a default route to the `tun`, and a specific route to the other end. You need to know the IP address of the other end, of course.

Comment: Search the site for "policy routing" and "iptables mark".

Comment: @dirkt - In my case, I want to be able to communicate directly with any server that has my app not just one ip. I don't have a gateway.

Comment: Then you do have to identify packets for that port, if it's the only distinguishing feature. As @grawity has said, "policy routing" and "iptables mark".